# Prevent PHP form sending with direct access, allow with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a script that fires off a email everytime someone comments on by FaceBook comment box. Fb.event.subscribe triggers a ajax call to mail.php on my server, which fires off a email to my email address to notify of a new comment. How do i make this more secure and block access to mail.php directly?

```
        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function (response) {
            var domain = "<?= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>";
            var url = "<?= $currentUrl ?>";
                alert("comment added");

                            var xmlhttp;
                            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                              }
                            else
                              {// code for IE6, IE5
                              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                              }

                            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://" + domain + "/mail.php?url=" + url,true);
                            xmlhttp.send();

        });


** ---------- here is mail.php -------- **



<?php 
    $to = "MY EMAIL HERE";
    $subject = "New Comment Added";
    $message = "New Comment posted here: " . $_GET['url'] ;
    $from = "MY EMAIL HERE";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    //mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    //echo  $_GET['accesstoken'] ;
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this. If you enable the client to access `mail.php` with client-side code, then anyone can access it with a script as well. You can try to obfuscate it as much as you want, but if someone really wants to find out how to access it they will.

**EDIT**: The basic rule is, if it can be done in a browser by a human, then it can be done in a script by a computer. The only semi counter-point to this rule are CAPTCHAs, but even these can be circumvented nowadays.

Comment: hmm .. so any recommendations?

Comment: Yes. You could access the graph API for your comments using PHP, https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=<your_url> parse the JSON in there and find out any new comments that you haven't processed yet. Since everything happens on the server side, then you won't have the spam issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a header check in your php script like this:

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    //send email
  }
?>
```

Comment: This may not be a perfect or a "proper" solution, but I think it would  reduce a small amount of flood in your app.

Comment: Just an extra measure. But the best bet would be to add some sort of permissions so that not everyone could access the email.php